# Improve this piece of code. Works but looks suspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i wish for any person to help improve this piece of code. It currently works but always looks suspect to me.

```
def sms
    @message = Message.new
    decoded_to = CGI.unescape(params[:to])
    #@message.to = decoded_to.gsub(/[^\d]/,"")
    @message.to = CGI.unescape(params[:to]).strip.gsub("+","").gsub(/\s+/, "")
    @message.from =  CGI.unescape(params[:from])
    @message.message = CGI.unescape(params[:message]).strip
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.status = 'Queued'
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, [""], current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "Success"} 
    else
        render json: {status: "Failed" }
    end
end
```

This an API controller that interacts with a shares Message model used by another controller. Its strictly for API interaction.

Comment: This is where you need to write Tests to remove the uncertainty and anxiety in your mind. And also just putting out a code like this isnt going to help. Explain the request type, what process is done and what response you are expecting.

Comment: Move all of this crap to the instantiation of the `Message` class. Something like this: [Clean up on Isle #5](http://pastebin.com/ih3HVupb)

Comment: I'd better do a kind of FormObject to handle all parameters processing before passing them to Message#new

Comment: This question is better suited for http://http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Separate out param cleaning logic:

```
def sms
    @message = Message.new(clean_params.merge(user: current_user, status: 'Queued'))
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, [""], current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "Success"} 
    else
        render json: {status: "Failed" }
    end
end

private

def clean_params
    cleaned_params = {}
    %i(to from message).each { |key| cleaned_params[key] = CGI.unescape(params[key]) }
    cleaned_params[:to].strip!.gsub!("+","").gsub!(/\s+/, "")
    cleaned_params[:message].strip!
    cleaned_params
end
```

Untested, I hope no typos got in ;)

Comment: Modifying params hash is not a great idea. See this http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/807-don-t-modify-the-params-hash

Comment: @AndreyKryachkov - right, I updated the code.